# Curved shower rod -- can I do a mixed mounting style?

Tags: shower, tile, drill, adhesive

I'm renting and the bathroom does not have a shower rod installed. I bought a curved one that can be drilled OR tension mounted, but the landlady does not want me to drill into tile.

The problem is that one side of the shower is regular drywall and the other side is tile. Could I drill into the drywall side and mount it with anchors, and then use the tension mount for the tile side? If I used silicon adhesive as well as tension, would that work better on the tile side? All I know so far is that using just tension is not holding up to daily usage with kids :-(

Comment: So far, you've experimented with using just tension. Since the landlord doesn't seem to mind you drilling into the drywall, what's to prevent you from experimenting with that? TBH, though, I'd guess that the issue is the _curved_ shower rod being held up with tension. Maybe try a straight tension-mount shower rod instead.

Comment: Have to upvote that - I think the curve is buying you a bunch of trouble here. Switch to a straight rod. Straight tension rods can be very reliable.